# Internet Explorer Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps, internet-explorer-8

Trying to work out why something isn't working in Internet Explorer 8 or lower, it appears to work in all other browsers.

The errors given by Internet Explorer 8 are:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
Timestamp: Fri, 4 Nov 2011 15:18:12 UTC

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 17
Char: 17840
Code: 0
URI: client.bytewire.co.uk/marblesolar/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.6.1

Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 30
Char: 1208
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/6/11/main.js

To replicate the error yourself

- Go to http://client.bytewire.co.uk/marblesolar/roof-calculator/
- Type in a UK post code e.g. GU12 4RQ and press search
- Draw a square by clicking 4 times then back onto the original point

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Elliot

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8;FF=3;OtherUA=4" />
```

put this into your head section it should resolve problem with javascript, now you are getting error because its not possible to get offsetWidth and height in quirks mode for ie

I think this will help you, it helped me.

Comment: Unfortunately this made no difference, try the tool out again, it still doesn't work correctly in IE 8.

Comment: The error is that you're trying to get DOM attributes on a document that has not been loaded.  I'd have to see more of the code to really understand what's going on.